# CloudKit vs Core Data and Memory Allocation

Tags: swift, core-data, memory-management, cloudkit

thanks for checking out my question. I am working on an app that uses both `Core Data` and `CloudKit`, when the user creates an object, I save various strings, floats, and image assets into both `Core Data` for quick local storage, but also to `CloudKit` as a backup option.  Just in case the data locally gets corrupted, or a user switches devices, I want them to always be able to access the data used by my app. Anyways, I've noticed when I program the app to load directly from `CloudKit`, bypassing the `Core Data` storage, that it ends up using almost twice as much memory as when there is local storage and nothing that requires updating from the cloud.  I always notice memory usage spikes that occur when I'm executing a `CloudKit` process like a `CKFetchRecordsOperation` or a `CKQuery`, but I would imagine that normally once the process is complete the memory would deallocate, and it's not. Essentially it's the exact same data being stored whether it gets pulled from `CloudKit` or `Core Data`, so I don't understand why one is allocating so much more memory than the other. Is it possible that I'm doing something wrong, and holding onto strong references, or is this a generally accepted disadvantage towards using `CloudKit`?

A more simple example would be this: User starts the app, and there isn't any data found locally through `Core Data` which triggers `CloudKit` to request the data stored in the cloud. Once all the data is retrieved and handled properly, then my app automatically saves that retrieved data to `Core Data` and continues on operating.  After fetching all the data from the cloud, the app is now operating at an average of 70MB of memory.  If I then close the app, and restart it, it will then find that data stored in `Core Data` and then won't require a `CloudKit` fetch, so it can proceed as normal.  When it works like this, and hasn't performed any CK operations, it operates at an average of 38MB of memory.

Does anybody have any clue as to why this may be happening? I'd share my code but I wouldn't even know where to start with this.

Comment: Generally a question like this is too broad for SO, but I realize that you're looking for help with where to even start troubleshooting. It's going to be really challenging to narrow it down with code running inside a larger application (too many factors, variables). You could try re-creating a very basic app from scratch that deals with very simple data that behaves the same way as your real app. Maybe you'll discover it's something else, or prove that it's CloudKit?

Comment: @brandonscript ~ Thank you for the response! I realized my question was so vague and probably would get rejected so I thank you for at least providing suggestions. And you're quite right that it's practically impossible to track down testing inside my large application. I'll try what you suggested.